# Private Parameters in a sub namespace

Tags: ros, remapping, parameter, namespace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a ROS node that essentially does this:

```
      ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
      ros::NodeHandle node_handle(nh, "derp"),
      node_handle.param<double>("rate", rate, 10.0);
```

Which means that the private parameter "rate" is pushed down into a namespace like so: derp/rate

I want to run aforementioned node from the command line and set this private parameter, but I do get errors.
If the parameter were not in a sub namespace i could just launch the node by

```
rosrun mypack mynode _rate:=100
```

Running the node via
rosrun mypack mynode derp/_rate:=100

Fails with a graph error. How can I set this private parameter via commandline?

Thanks!

Edit: running this with a launch file like so works:

```
<node name="mynode" pkg="mypack" type="mynode" output="screen"">
    <param name="derp/rate" value="100.0" />
</node>
```

But I do need to set this parameter via commandline.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217030/private-parameters-in-a-sub-namespace/) by [Crusty](https://answers.ros.org/users/5011/crusty/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2015-09-03

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-03**:
Just to make sure: the `_hz` suffix is only in your launch file example, not any of the command lines. Your C++ excerpt also doesn't show it. Are these the same nodes?

**Comment by [Crusty](https://answers.ros.org/users/5011/crusty/) on 2015-09-03**:
Typo only local to this post, fixed thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try:

```
 rosrun mypack mynode _derp/rate:=100
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Crusty](https://answers.ros.org/users/5011/crusty/) on 2015-09-03**:
Tested, sadly doesnt work, node still running at 10Hz :(

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-09-03**:
When I run a node with that syntax, it correctly sets the parameter. Are you sure you didn't make a typo in the parameter name?

**Comment by [Crusty](https://answers.ros.org/users/5011/crusty/) on 2015-09-03**:
Yep, it was just a copy paste error to here. I tried reducing and simplifying the example to the essence for the sake of posting it here distraction-free. The topic is indeed called rate_hz everywhere in my code.

**Comment by [Crusty](https://answers.ros.org/users/5011/crusty/) on 2015-09-04**:
I tested this again today, and it works, thanks. I added some debugging statements, and turns out the rate got set correctly, but the publishing speed was still always at 10 Hz. So I concluded it didn't work.  The slow publishing had other reasons in the code I am working with.